# How to use the Liferay "comments framework"?

Tags: api, comments, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to use the built-in comments functionality within a JSF 2.0/ICEfaces portlet application (the application is running fine already). Unfortunately there seems to be no detailed documentation about the comments stuff yet so I hope somebody can give me some pointers how to create and retrieve comments that should be linked to a single integer.

To be more clear... I'd like to (re-)use the "Page Comments" portlet's functionality within my custom portlet, but only the underlying service, not the UI part.

I already figured out that MBMessageServiceUtil.addDiscussionMessage(...) is used by that portlet through the EditDiscussionAction class. Unfortunately I have no clue what I should provide as parameter values. Could anybody shed some light on this? The [javadoc](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/messageboards/service/MBMessageServiceUtil.html#addDiscussionMessage%28long,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29) is kind of... short ;-)

```
public static MBMessage addDiscussionMessage(long groupId,
                                             String className,
                                             long classPK,
                                             String permissionClassName,
                                             long permissionClassPK,
                                             long threadId,
                                             long parentMessageId,
                                             String subject,
                                             String body,
                                             ServiceContext serviceContext)
```

Cheers,
tamm0r

Answer (score 5):

This is going to be long but here is the play by play.

1. In your view, you're going to grab the MBMessageDisplay object.

```java
    MBMessageDisplay messageDisplay =
       MBMessageLocalServiceUtil.getDiscussionMessageDisplay(
          themeDisplay.getUserId(), themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(),
          MyModelEntry.class.getName(), myModelEntry.getTasksEntryId(),
          WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED);
```

1. MBMessageDisplay will contain vital data like the threadId and parentMessageId, so be sure to post this data as well.
2. In the "Controller" where you make the call mentioned in your post grab the ServiceContext from the request like so:

   ```java
   ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(
      MyModelEntry.class.getName(), actionRequest);
   ```
3. So you now have all the parameters required.

   ```java
   long groupId - Group (Organization or Community usually) you're writing the comment in.
   String className - MyModelEntry.class.getName()
   long classPK - MyModelEntry's Primary Key or ID
   String permissionClassName - Model where the permission checker should look, typically the same as className
   long permissionClassPK - Its Primary Key or Id
   long threadId - From MBMessageDisplay.
   long parentMessageId - From MBMessageDisplay.
   String subject - the subject
   String body - the body
   ServiceContext serviceContext - from Request in step 3.
   ```

Hope this helps!